# Efficient script developing in Python

Tags: python, testing, data-cleaning

When making changes to larger modules, this is my current (inefficient) process:

1. Make needed change to code
2. Run program to test (using pdb - `python3 -m pdb path/to/script.py`
3. Program will throw an error
4. Fix error/create an exception
5. Run again
6. New error appears
7. Rinse an repeat

The data processing module I'm working on has many steps, and rerunning every time I make a code change to make sure there are no errors takes a long time and it's frustating. It's also obviously an inefficient way to develop a program, but I don't know what alternative

What advice do you have so that I don't have to run, and wait for, my whole data processing pipeline to find what the next error will be? Is there any way to make changes on the code and continue executing before the last error appeared?

Answer (score 1):

You could do unit testing for every module and for every steps. Basically it's "create fake data to pass to every step and check if the result after the step is what you want", obviously automated.

Check the internet to learn about testing in general and testing in Python.

Comment: Thank you! It makes sense. I'm not very familiar with test-driven programming so I'll definitely look into how to incorporate it into my developing process. Do you have any particular links about testing for data processing in particular?

Comment: I think that in your case the module doctest is the best solution, I don't know exactly what you have to do but it's simply and fast to write tests with it.